# How do I open GTK Inspector?

Tags: gtk3

I am using GTK.3.15. When attempting to open GTK Inspector using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>,
nothing happens. Does not matter what application or widget I am using. Nothing happens

and my understanding is that this option comes standard on GTK 3.15. Does anyone know how

to use this tool in GTK 3.15?

Comment: Did you tried with my answer?

Comment: The dconf-editor does not have the debug feature that you speak of. I did attempt to update the application but Ubuntu tells me that I have the newest version installed. I do appreciate your help though. It looks like I will have to wait a few weeks for the release of Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put arrows in my answer. I meant `org` > `gtk` > `Settings` > `Debug`. I think that

Comment: No arrows were needed. I understood exactly what you were telling me.

Comment: I tried it on my computer and it couldn't find `debug` entry. However, did it work the 2nd method?

Comment: The org.gtk.settings.debug entry shows up in the gsettings schema after installing the `libgtk-3-dev` package.

Answer (score 30):

I got this from https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector:

> GtkInspector is the built-in interactive debugging support in GTK+. It was added in GTK+ 3.14, based on a copy of the well-estabished gtkparasite.
>
> The debugger is disabled by default. To enable it run in a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding true
```

> And launch it pressing on the keyboard Control-Shift-I or Control-Shift-D.
>
> If you don't want to use the shortcuts, you can also run it temporarily directly when running your app with:

```
GTK_DEBUG=interactive your-app
```

Looking further, I found [Bug #1523929](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1523929) which indicates that users can install `libgtk-3-dev` which then provides the schema. Note that installing `libgtk-3-dev` may bring in a lot of dependencies.

Comment: How do I open the inspector in browser that use ctrl+shit+i (or ctrl+shift+d) as shorcuts for other tasks?

Comment: I can't inspect even after installing `libgtk-3-dev`. Looked in the help menu, no inspector help. Looked in key bindings and no option for opening the inspector.

Comment: Cool. Do you know how much overhead this adds to running GTK3 apps?

Answer (score 16):

#### Method 1:

---

Enable the shortcut:

1. Install `dconf-editor` with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
2. Navigate to `org` > `gtk` > `settings` > `debug`
3. Set `enable-inspector-keybinding` to `true`
4. Try the shortcut.

#### Method 2:

---

Run the program to debug with the `GTK_DEBUG` variable:

Instead of running the program to debug as usual (`myprogram --argument`) you only need to run it of this way (`GTK_DEBUG=interactive myprogram --argument`)

Also you can export that variable with `export GTK_DEBUG=interactive` and then run the program.

Comment: No it's not necessary to reboot or to log out+in after using dconf. If you ever find a case where a dconf change doesn't "take" until you re-login, it's a bug. Report it.

Comment: dconf is missing `Debug` for me. Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This didn't work for me even after installing `libgtk-3-dev`. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome 3.28.3

Comment: This seems to be the last documentation: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled

Comment: @CostaMichailidis This works for me: `GTK_DEBUG=interactive gtk3-demo`

Answer (score 4):

**Updated:** 2023-01

The wiki page for the Inspector seems to be a bit out of date, and at times bugs interfere with documented functionality. What's more, a lot of this functionality is implemented inconsistently in applications, which has clearly led to a lot of people being steered in a lot of wrong directions. (Including by previous versions of this answer.)

> If you don't want to use the shortcuts, you can also open the Inspector directly when running your app with:

The handling of `GTK_DEBUG` does appear to have been fixed, so that `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` in the environment will auto-open the inspector. That wasn't working for me in the past, but in Fedora 37 it works as described.

> To launch the GTK Inspector, focus your GTK application and press `Control-Shift-D`. Alternatively, move your mouse cursor to your desired widget and press `Control-Shift-I` to specifically inspect the widget under the mouse cursor.

So, turns out these statements are *correct**-ish***, but they should be accompanied by a whole bunch of caveats.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> *might work*, **if the application hasn't bound it to something else**.
- Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> *might work*, under the same conditions.

  And while it is, technically, a context-sensitive shortcut that will inspect "the widget under the mouse cursor", many applications draw their entire interface inside a big `GtkDrawingArea` so don't be surprised if that's the widget that pops up for most mouse locations. (You won't be able to inspect anything inside that area, anyway, as the contents are not Gtk widgets.)
- If an application **has** bound away one or both of the shortcuts, its local bindings will override and there's nothing you can do about that.

  - Nautilus, in particular, has a different binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (it's "Invert selection"), so that shortcut will never work to open the inspector in Nautilus, and you have to use only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
  - Gnome Terminal actually binds **both** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, so neither shortcut will work... which is why they provide a handy **Help > Inspector** option in the application menubar (if you activate that).
- Last but not least, [there's a bug in Gtk's handling](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/5411) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> that might prevent it from working every other time you try to use it. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> doesn't seem to be affected.)

To get to the inspector, you'll need to satisfy the items on this list:

1. Install the appropriate `gtk3-devel` / `libgtk-3-dev` or `gtk4-devel` / `libgtk-4-dev` package. Non-optional.
2. If using Gtk3, enable the dconf key `/org/gtk/settings/debug/enable-inspector-keybinding` / GSettings key `org.gtk.Settings.Debug enable-inspector-keybinding`. (They're the same setting.) Optionally, you can disable `org.gtk.Settings.Debug inspector-warning`.

   Gtk4 has its own `enable-inspector-keybinding` key at `org.gtk.gtk4.settings.debug`, but it now defaults `True` so you're probably already good there. `org.gtk.gtk4.settings.debug.inspector-warning` still also defaults to `True`, though, so you may want to turn that off.
3. *Either*:

   - Run a program with `GTK_DEBUG=interactive` in the environment.
   - When the application is open and focused, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and hope one of them works. Or look for a menu option to do the same thing.

Comment: Nice, thanks. For gnome-terminal, select Advanced > Inspector. Ctrl/Shift/D appeared to work for me, but CSS changes didn't take effect. This whole thing is a real mess.

Comment: @EML I guess Ctrl+Shift+d might depend on what your shortcuts bindings are set to... but on my system it doesn't work, despite not being listed anywhere as a bound shortcut. The terminal appears to interpret it the same as Ctrl+d. ...As for CSS, that _should_ work... the trick is that the actual terminal session is run inside a black-box `vte-terminal` widget with no CSS support. But you can style other widgets, e.g. `menubar { font-weight: bold; }` or `notebook box label { font-weight: bold; }` worked for me, to bold the window's menu items / tab titles.