# Class and Id picker Tool for creating Theme

Tags: 16.04, themes, customization

I want tools for creating Ubuntu Theme. I know i can tweak other themes and create my own but I need something to pick `class` and `id` like what color picker do for colors.

For example, I need a tool when i click on Unity Panel Menu Bar shows me `.unity-panel .menubar .menuitem`

Is there any tool for that?

Comment: Not exactly what you want,  [GTK Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector) works only with GTK3 (AFAIK) . Here is how to enable it https://askubuntu.com/questions/597259/how-do-i-open-gtk-inspector

Comment: Thanks. It's near to what I want but It doesn't work with everything.