# How to change the size of titlebar buttons?

Tags: 20.04, window-buttons

How can I change the size of titlebar/window buttons? Changing the fractional scaling to 125% causes many other problems, so I'm avoiding it.

Comment: Try "Font Scaling" in "Gnome Tweaks" to enlarge or reduce the user font somewhat. That will not change graphics size, but still will allow you to not feel that the display is too small/too large. Apart from scaling, the size of buttons cannot be changed without editing the source code of the style.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this with some `gtk.css` styles. Note that this won't affect programs that set their own window titlebar styling, like Firefox, for example.

1. Create a file named `gtk.css` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0`.
2. Enter this CSS code. This specific style makes the buttons more Windows-like (it removes the space to the right of the close button and makes the click targets fill the height of the window titlebar), but feel free to modify as you see fit.

   ```css
   headerbar {
     padding-right: 0;
   }

   .titlebutton {
     min-width: 44px;
     min-height: 44px;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
3. Save the file, then log out and back in to apply the changes.

If you'd like to do some extended tweakage, I'd recommend poking around with GTK+ Inspector like I did: https://askubuntu.com/a/1377091/1587412