# Remove space between tabs in Terminator

Tags: 20.04, terminator

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Terminator 1.91. In Ubuntu 20.04, there are spaces between tabs and bordes of main window.

[image]

Could you please advise if there is some way to remove these spaces?

I don't see such problem in Ubuntu 18.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use GtkInspector to debug this kind of issue, and figure out which CSS style need be updated. You can find some reference [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597259/how-do-i-open-gtk-inspector).

```
GTK_DEBUG=interactive terminator
```

And here's the fix:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/gtk-3.0
vim ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

.terminator-terminal-window notebook tabs {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Those spaces should be gone, after restarting terminator.

Comment: Note to self and everyone getting confused: Starting terminator with GTK_DEBUG from a terminator terminal does not work as expected, since this will only create a new window of the running terminator process, so setting the environment variable has no effect on the new terminal window. One workaround: use another terminal (xterm) and run the above mentioned command.