# How we can increase the icon size more than the maximum available in application grid? (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, DE - Ubuntu)

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

Is there any possibility to increase the icon size more than the maximum available in Gnome Tweaks or any other method in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? May be it is somehow possible to do this. If any experienced user knows, I request them to share. Thanks. :

[image]

For me the minimum app icon size should be like when app icon appears when searched (For reference I am attaching picture below):
[image]

Ideally it must also auto-magnify on mouse hover but for now I am not requesting that much functionality but it must increase in size simultaneously utilising all the space around.

Comment: which icons are you referring to?

Comment: I edited the question with an image. How can we enlarge those icons in app section more than the maximum size available in the settings? They could look better if there is some way to enlarge them further. Also it will utilise the space available for aesthetics. Another request pertaining this same question is if it is still possible to enlarge them further on mouse hover, it would be even better.

Comment: might it be the same as this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/785620/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-lts-reduce-icon-size (that one is about making them smaller ;))

Comment: There must be some easy way by now to increase app icon size in application grid. I do not have much points but I have kept this question on bounty nevertheless in the hope that something good and easy would be there. There must be some extension or may be by default it should let us change the icon size in there. The app icons does not have to look tiny, there must be way to increase icon size in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (DE Ubuntu)

Comment: @Rinzwind, the question you pointed out was posted in 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04. Are you sure it works without any breakage on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS? I do not want to risk anything because it has taken some time to get my desktop to present condition and I am new Linux user. I would wish someone knowledgeable writes a better answer for this for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS release. Thank you.

Comment: Naa, not sure. But it will probably point to the same method: you need to track down the binairy that holds the xml that has the icon size in it. It might even be theme dependent.

Comment: @Maverick You might be able to experiment with the [GTK inspector](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597259/how-do-i-open-gtk-inspector) and verify that the CSS tweaks still work

Comment: @James EJ I only wish as feature request that this will be added in future versions of Ubuntu for common users to easily do this. The grouping of icons inside app section problem I was having is solved in Ubuntu 20.10 and above. That is really a good thing that has happened in development but the icons size needs to increase too and if possible with icon magnification on mouse hover.